# Getting orientation of the device?

Tags: android

I have a camera preview activity, which is forced to stay in landscape mode.

Is there a way I can tell the current orientation of the phone (not the screen orientation).

Basically I want to know if the user is holding the phone in portrait mode, or in landscape mode, so I can rotate the output captured bitmap correctly (right now it just always outputs in landscape mode).

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://www.workingfromhere.com/blog/2009/03/30/orientation-sensor-tips-in-android/ ?

Comment: Thanks Nathan, that's a solution. Seems to work well (replaced the deprecated sensor listener classes). Although this works, I was hoping they'd have an easier solution, like context.whatsMyCurrentOrientation(). Oh well! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        {   
            p.set("orientation", "portrait");

            ....
        }
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {   
            p.set("orientation", "landscape");
            ....
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement [Application.onConfigurationChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)) to respond to orientation changes without having to register a `SensorEventListener`.  It might be an easier way to go if you want to customize the layout depending on the phone orientation.