# Orientation Lock

Tags: android

How can I prevent my app form rotating. I want it so if the user is in portrait mode, the app will always be in portrait mode, and if they start the app in landscape the app will always be in lanscape (until the app is closed and started again)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void lockOrientation(Activity a) {
    if (a.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    } else {
        a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
}

public static void unlockOrientation(Activity a) {
    a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
}
```

Comment: This answer will give the wrong behaviour if the device is in reverse-portrait or reverse-landscape orientation.

Comment: @Dan Hulme That's true I've discovered that recently, too. I haven't yet thought how to improve the answer do you know?

Comment: I proposed an edit to the question which is stemmed off of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388846/how-to-detect-exact-orientation-of-device-in-froyo