# Screen orientation to portrait and reverse portrait

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-screen-support

My app target 2.2 and later and want to support orientation only on portrait and reverse portrait.  and the problem is i can't declare

> android:screenOrientation="reversePortrait"

in manifest as it is only available from api level 9. 
How is it possible to do this by supporting android 2.2 and later.

Answer (score 1):

According to this post,

[How to detect exact orientation of device in Froyo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388846/how-to-detect-exact-orientation-of-device-in-froyo)

it is not possible to use portrait mode with reversed API 8.